# Bug with `LocalObjects` leaking evaluation of `LocalSymbol`

Tags: bugs, localsymbol

```
Quit

LocalSymbol["x"] = x;

Quit

Names@"Global`*"
LocalObjects[]
Names@"Global`*"

{}

{LocalObject[
  "file:///C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Roaming/Wolfram/Objects/LocalSymbols/\
x"]}

{"x"}

Quit

Names@"Global`*"
LocalObject["x"]
Names@"Global`*"

{}

LocalObject["file:///C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Roaming/Wolfram/Objects/x"]

{}
```

as you can see, `LocalObject["x"]` doesn't leak creation of the symbol `x` that the local object refers to. `LocalObjects[]` does.

Worth reporting?

Comment: This might leak quite some memory when we use LocalObjects/LocalSymbols to store "packages". It's as if `LocalObjects[]` parsed all of your package files at once.

Comment: I filed a report.

Comment: They replied "Thank you for your observations. I have filed a report with our developers for their consideration."